# Access Facebook Data - Offline Access

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a question regarding the Facebook API and would like to gain some insight into nuts and bolts of the Facebook API.

I'm planning to write an App in PHP. This would be a birthday alert app. A user would visit our website, login wih their Facebook Account and done - We send them alerts as and when their friends have birthdays.

How can this app work in the background? because connections for a user keeps on changing. We cannot store all the data in a database because of two things:

```
 1) Constantly evolving connections
 2) Violates Facebook Terms.
```

We need to be able to store only the UID's of the users and then use that UID to somehow fetch a users connections and their corresponding date of birth on a daily basis.

Please let me know if this can be done or not, Because what i've learnt so far of the Facebook API, we'll need an Access Token to access a users personal information. And this Access Token is persistent only for the time until he/she is logged in.

I'm sure there might be some other way to achieve this that i might have overlooked.

I would highly appreciate if any of you could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to request `offline_access` extended permission to be able to retreive user data anytime. In order to get friends birthday there is `friends_birthday` permission. More about permissions [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions).

Comment: Thanks Serg, i already had that figured out from some other StackOverflow question.. :) thanks.! +1